# How to refresh the page with <a> tag in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have some `<a>` tag that need to refresh the entire page, because it need to execute php code in the backend.

Now it just only change the route in the address bar.

Comment: can you post the code on how you are referencing the url in the <a> tag

Comment: Using a normal hyperlink? `a href="/bla"`?

Comment: <a href="/auth/logout">登出</a>

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<a href="/somelink" > Link </a>
```

Comment: `_self` is the default, so your `target` attribute does nothing. It's not needed actually. A simple hyperlink is enough.

Comment: this wont work,i tried add attribute:target="_self",and it does work,ty

Answer (score 0):

use ng-click for that.

```
<a href="#" ng-click="loadPage()">load</a>
```

and in the controller define a function

```
$scope.loadPage = function() {window.location('path to load')}
```

hope it will work.

Comment: Why would you write a JS function and handle a click event to achieve something a HTML hyperlink does "by default"?

Comment: this method will do a full-refresh.$route.reload() also work.

Comment: Yeah, `a href="/the_same_url"` will also work. Why would anyone use JavaScript to achieve the exact same thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a ng-href="#" > Link </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this question by myself. You just need to add `target="_self"` attribute on that `<a>` tag.